# Installing eclipse plugin via command line [Windows]

Tags: eclipse, plugins, p2

i wanted to install a eclipse plugin via the command line and not with the eclipse gui and not with the dropin folder.

i found out that it is possible with this command:

```
eclipsec.exe -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 
-repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/ 
-installIU org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group 
-tag AddCDT
```

but i have no idea how the command looks like when i download the plugin as .zip and install it from my local C: drive

e.g my plugin folder looks like this:

- C:\MyPlugin\

  - \plugins\
  - \features\
  - ......xml

many thanks

Comment: When the ZIP contains an update site (containing a `artifacts.jar` or `artifacts.xml` and a `content.jar` or `content.xml`), unzip the ZIP and use `-repository file:/...`, e.g. on Windows something like `-repository file:/C:/path/to/unzipped/dir/`. Otherwise, copy it into the `dropins` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
-repository jar:file:/C:/temp/your_zipped_plugin.zip!/
```

(found this from https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/wdfrhcw/1.4.0?topic=eclipse-silent-installation)